# No resource found when I change build variants from debug to release

Tags: android, build, build.gradle

[image]I am facing this issue from few weeks when I change build variants from debug to release it will give me the following error:

```
Error:(213, 37) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/themeGray').
```

[image]For every resource file that image or string already present in respective folder if anyone know about this issue please help.

Comment: post your colors.xml code

Comment: there is no value for  '@color/themeGray

Comment: when i change gradle variant debug to release these values getting disappear from its resource i.e String.xml  and  drawble folder